# Cut Corners using JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

I'm looking to "cut" the top left corner of a tab, like if you had folded the corner of a page down.

Are there any methods?

My code:

```
.tab:before {
-fx-position: absolute;
-fx-top: 0;
-fx-right: 0;
-fx-border-top: 300px solid white;
-fx-border-left: 200px solid red;
-fx-width: 0;
-fx-background-color: transparent;}
```

return:

> .jar!/css/tabs.css: expected series of  while parsing '-fx-border-top' at [9,20]

Answer (score 3):

Many of these properties are not supported: I don't know where you are getting them from.

There is no `-fx-position`, `-fx-top`, `-fx-right` property (in general, JavaFX CSS is used for *style*, not for *layout*).

There is no `-fx-border-top` or `-fx-border-right` property: border sizes are specified by `-fx-border-width: top right bottom left` syntax, and similarly border colors are specified by `-fx-border-color`. There is a `-fx-border-radius` property, which I think is the one you are looking for.

There is no `:before` pseudoclass.

So you can try something like this (which is not tested; provide a complete example in your question if you want tested code in the answers):

```
.tab {
    -fx-border-color: white, red ;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1 ;
    -fx-border-radius: 5 0 0 0 ;
}
```

Refer to the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for an actual list of defined properties.

It's also worth noting that in the default styles, borders are almost never used directly. The preferred way of creating a border effect in modena is to use "nested backgrounds". Using this approach your CSS might look like:

```
.tab {
    -fx-background-color: white, red, -fx-body-color ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 0 0, 1 0 0 1 ;
    -fx-background-radius: 10 0 0 0 ;
}
```

For more complex shapes (other than just rectangles with rounded corners), you could also use the `-fx-shape` property, using SVG syntax to define the shape of the tab.

It's useful to look at the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for the default stylesheet to see how this all works. You probably want to change the styles for `.tab:selected` to make selection play nicely with your styles.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do it a lazy way, set the image in the background in the format I wanted and left the background transparent.

```
.tab {
-fx-background-image: url("../icons/pane.png");
-fx-background-size: stretch;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
```

[Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKmOo.png)